# Euler method in c++

Tags: c++

The following code uses Euler's Method to approximate a value of y(x). My code currently accepts the endpoints a and b as user input and values for values for alpha which is the initial condition and the step size value which is h. Given my code I can now approximate a value of y, say y(8) given the initial condition y(0)=6.

However I have a small mistake in my code and I am not quite sure how to fix it and am looking for help. Right now my code does not check to ensure that the right endpoint b is an integer multiple of the stepsize h. Due to this the final approximation may not be for f(b) but for f(c) where c is the closest integer multiple of h to b. I am looking for some help on how to fix this, Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

double dydx (double x, double y)
    {
        double f = y*(2-y)/(x+3);
        return f;
    }
int main()
{
    double a,b,alpha,h,z;
    cout<<"\nEnter the value of endpoint a: \n";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"\nEnter the value of endpoint b: \n";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"\nEnter the y value of the initial condition: \n";
    cin>>alpha;
    cout<<"\nEnter the stepsize, h: \n";
    cin>>h;
    cout<<"\n";
    while((b-a)>0.0000001)
    {
        z=alpha+(h*dydx(a,alpha));
        cout<<"z("<<a<<")="<<z<<endl;
        alpha=z;
        a=a+h;
    }
    cout<<"\nThe approximate solution of y("<<b<<") is "<<z<<"."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can input number of steps, instead of step size

Comment: Please add some examples like 
"for these inputs, the right answer is ... but my program shows ..."

Comment: @SemyonBurov could you show how this would be possible?

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to execute each statement separately and *watch* values of variables.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am not quite sure what exactly is going wrong with the values of my variables

Comment: If you give a stepwise that  doesn't divide b-a evenly then you could step past b.  I think this is what @Semyon was getting at.

Comment: @emsr it seems like his answer he posted works correctly

Comment: @emsr do you have a edit for my code that could fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate step size `h` from number of steps `n`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

double dydx (double x, double y)
    {
        double f = y*(2-y)/(x+3);
        return f;
    }
int main()
{
    double a,b,alpha,h,z;
    cout<<"\nEnter the value of endpoint a: \n";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"\nEnter the value of endpoint b: \n";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"\nEnter the y value of the initial condition: \n";
    cin>>alpha;
    /*
     * Obtains step size from number on steps
     * h = 0.1 for [a; b] = [0; 8] can be given by n = 80
    */
    int n = 0;
    cout<<"\nEnter the number of steps, n: \n";
    cin>>n;
    h = (b - a) / n;
    //------
    cout<<"\n";
    //-- Replaced 0.0000001 by h / 2.0 --
    while((b-a)> h / 2.0)
    {
        z=alpha+(h*dydx(a,alpha));
        alpha=z;
        a=a+h;
        /* 
         * z - function value in next point, 
         * so to output correct point a need to be incremented before this.   
        */
        cout<<"z("<<a<<")="<<z<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\nThe approximate solution of y("<<b<<") is "<<z<<"."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Insert this instead of `h` input.

Comment: okay so replace,  
    cout<<"\nEnter the stepsize, h: \n";
    cin>>h;

with that?

Comment: my code needs to prompt the user to input the step size not the number of steps. When I plugged your suggestion in and tried it gave me -infinity. So how can I fix this?

Comment: for the inputs 0 8 6 0.1 my current code I have wrote in my question gives:  the approximate solution of y(8) is 2.09045

Comment: it also gives all the prior steps like z(0)=5.2, z(0.1)=4.66323 all the way up to z(7.9)=2.09045

Comment: I have added 2 pictures to the question detailing my output

Comment: so what do I need to swap out? and what happens if I use a different stepsize, why did you choose n=80?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155431/discussion-between-semyon-burov-and-jh123).